# How to use CFileFind in MFC Smart Device Application VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cfile, cfilefind

I am getting error like this

```
 error C2065: 'CFileFind' : undeclared identifier
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'finder' 
 error C2065: 'finder' : undeclared identifier  
 error C2065: 'finder' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: It's saying it doesn't understand `CFileFind` so you're missing a header or you're using functionality not supported on smart devices.

Answer (score 0):

From the CFileFind documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f33e1618(v=VS.80).aspx

"This class is not supported in Smart Device projects"